# How to use if statement in query model

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datatables

Tried searching but haven't found an answer that solves my problem. I want to include an if condition in this query select:

```
    $this->datatables->select('id,username,password,email,is_active,is_role,created_at,updated_at');

    $this->datatables->add_column('action', anchor(site_url('ms_users/read/$1'), 'Read') . " | " . anchor(site_url('ms_users/update/$1'), 'Update') . " | " . anchor(site_url('ms_users/delete/$1'), 'Delete', 'onclick="javasciprt: return confirm(\'Are You Sure ?\')"'), 'id');
    return $this->datatables->generate();
```

**I want to make like this for is_active and is_role:**

```
    /* 
    if (is_active == 1) {
        echo "Active";
    } else {
        echo "Nonaktif";
    }
    */

    /* 
    if (is_role == 1) {
        echo "Admin";
    } else if (is_role == 2){
        echo "Users";
    }
    */
```

Comment: What should is_role be if it is neither 1 or 2?

Comment: You would use a case expression for this

Comment: I use is_role to differentiate dashboard between users.

Comment: is_role can be more than two, that's why I use else if

Comment: My understanding is that you want your query to return "Admin" as is_role if is_role in the database is 1, and "Users" if it is 2.  Am I understanding correctly?  What do you want returned if it is more than 2?

Comment: Yes, that's right, I just want to know how to query it. And actually, I want to show "Admin" or "Users" in the list table only.

Comment: Then what do you want to happen if is_role is more than 2?

Comment: if there are more than 2 i want to show "Other users"

Comment: Please don't make trivial edits in order to submit your question for review; all that accomplishes is waste people's time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe like this

```
$this->datatables->select('id,username,password,email,if(is_active=1,"Active","Nonaktif") as is_active,if(is_role=1,"Admin",if(is_role=2,"Users","Other users")) as is_role,created_at,updated_at');
```

or

try use CASE statement for more than 2 roles

```
$this->datatables->select('id,username,password,email,if(is_active=1,'Active','Nonaktif') as is_active,CASE 
        WHEN is_role = 1 THEN "Admin"
        WHEN is_role = 2 THEN "Users"
        ELSE "Other User"
    END AS is_role,created_at,updated_at');
```